# opacity propagation

Tags: css, transparency

I've got a problem. I want a transparent background for the content div. But not all content in it. I can't get this working:

```
<div class="notTransparent"> <div class="transparent"></div> content </div>
```

Is there another work around??

Comment: Perhaps you could also post the CSS rules for `.transparent` and `.notTransparent`?

Comment: Just to clarify; don't you have your example `div` tags backwards there? You are talking about having the transparent one on the outside, but the opaque one on the inside, right?

Comment: @Andrew Barber: I think the divs are the correct way round - I think what dododedodonl (I deserve an up-rating just for spelling that right!) is that they want the word "content" opaque, but the div behind that to be slightly transparent. This way a slightly faded background could be placed behind the word "content". However the word should be in its own div, as in my answer. The result being that anything behind the outer panel would not be visible, anything inside the transparent div would be slightly faded and anything outside it would be completely opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have done this before (although it was ages ago). What you do is have a div with display: relative, then another div within that with display: absolute, left: 0px, top: 0px, width: 100% and height: 100%. Maybe apply z-index: -10 (to put this behind all other content). You then have the content within the top level (relative) div as normal. Give me a few minutes and I will work out the code for ya...

Ok done that - try the following:

```
.transparent {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.opaque {
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

<div class="opaque">
    <div class="transparent">
        <img src="/Images/header1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to place a relative element over the transparent div. If anyone finds a way then please paste the code here. By the way there is actually no need to specify any z-indexes.

Answer (score 3):

CSS rgba

http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/
http://www.css3.info/preview/opacity/

Comment: no. For IE7+ you can use a transparent (1x1) PNG as a fallback inside a conditional stylesheet. For IE6, just nevermind about it, unless you are making a site for China or India.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into inheritance problems with transparency a while back, this did the trick for me: http://blog.ninanet.com/2010/04/27/css-transparency-inheritance-hack ([demo](http://ninanet.com/devdemos/transparency.php)).